# Call a Fragment method from an Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a method `sendData()` in my fragment. This method starts a new Activity. I want to call this method from my `ArrayAdapter`.

Here is my code:-

HomeFragment.java

```
stagAdaper = new StaggeredAdapter(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList);
            mGridView.setAdapter(stagAdaper);
    private void sendData(int position)
    {

        myDialog = new ProgressDialog(myContext).show(getActivity(), "Fetching news..", "Just a moment");

        myDialog.getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.openarticlewaitprogress);
        myDialog.getWindow().setTitle("Loading..");
        myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
         new  NewsDetails(myDialog);



            Intent nIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),Details.class);

               String Body=getList.get(position).getBody();

            newsIntent.putExtra("Body", Body);


            startActivity(nIntent);

    }
```

StaggeredAdapter.java

```
viewHolder.layGridLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //viewHolder.layGridLayout.setForeground(R.drawable.foreground_selector);

        }
    });
    return convertView;
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: look this and you learn how to communicate Fragments :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081101/using-localbroadcastmanager-to-communicate-from-fragment-to-activity/24083101#24083101

Answer (score 172, accepted):

**Edit :**
Here is what I would use now. Older, "easier" solutions are available below.

```
MyFragment extends Fragment implements CustomAdapter.EventListener {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(..., this);

    }

    void onEvent(int data) {
        doSomething(data);
    }

}

CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    EventListener listener; 

    public interface EventListener {
        void onEvent(int data);   
    }

    public CustomAdapter(..., EventListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener; 
    }

    ...

}
```

Now from any place in the adapter we can call `listener.onEvent(data);` to trigger the method in the fragment.

Moreover, instead of providing a listener through the constructor, we can add another method in the adapter such as `registerListener(EventListener eventListener)` and then maintain a list of listeners if needed.

**Old Answer:**

Solution 1 : 
Make the adapter an inner class of your fragment, so that you can call the method directly.

Solution 2 :
Update your adapter constructor to accept the Fragment as a parameter.

Something like :

```
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList, HomeFragment.this);
```

and update the constructor of the Adapter :

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int id, HomeFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

then you call methods using the fragment variable.

```
fragment.doSomething();
```

Comment: I tried this. But then I get a NullPointerException at the ProgressDialog variable

Comment: @user3713706 this solution must be worked, post your logcat, maybe you have an error in some where else

Comment: @Shivam It worked had a issue somewhere else. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solution is the best and simplest one among the ones I came across.

Comment: how  to call    from OnBindViewholder ?

Comment: If i choose solution 2, when fragment is destroyed, will it be released from memory? It is because I worry that  fragment retain adapter and adapter retain fragment (loop).

Comment: @KhantThuLinn Yes, I think it will be garbage collected. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910203/1239966

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late to answer but There are 2 ways more to do it:

1. You can also send `broadcast` from `adapter` and register it in `fragment`.
2. Use interface. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348590/4291272) SO question for details.

Comment: This one is considerable.

Answer (score -4):

You can make sendData method as **static**

```
public static void sendData(int position)
{
     ......
}
```

n call it as

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     HomeFragment.sendData(position)
     ........    
}
```

Comment: If I do that I cannot access getActivity()

Comment: you can use **myContext** instead