# how to call getsupportfragmentmanager() from adapter class?

Tags: android

I have `ViewPager` as the first item inside a `RecyclerView`.I want to set `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to the `viewpager` inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method.
But i can't call `getsupportfragmentmanager()`.Please help!!.
Here's my code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<RowItem> rowItemList;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_CUSTOM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 1;
    NewPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItemList = rowItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return VIEW_TYPE_CUSTOM;
        else
            return VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rowItemList.size()+1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_CUSTOM:
                recViewHolder1 viewHolderSecond = (recViewHolder1) holder;
                    mCustomPagerAdapter = new NewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    viewHolderSecond.vPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL:
                recViewHolder2 viewHolderFirst = (recViewHolder2) holder;
                RowItem rowItem = rowItemList.get(position-1);
                viewHolderFirst.vName.setText(rowItem.getName());
                viewHolderFirst.vImage.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_CUSTOM:
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                        from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.pagerlayout, parent, false);
                return new recViewHolder1(itemView);
            case VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL:
                View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.
                        from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
                return new recViewHolder2(itemView1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }


    public static class recViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected static ViewPager vPager;


        public recViewHolder1(View v) {
            super(v);
            vPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.vPager);
        }
    }

    public class recViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected  TextView vName;
        protected  ImageView vImage;

        public recViewHolder2(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vName);
            vImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.vImage);
        } } }
```

Comment: You need to pass it in the constructor to adapter from Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 94):

i solved it by casting mContext

```
((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
```

Comment: With this proposal I am getting runtime error MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: Inconvertible types.

Answer (score 34):

Its Best solution is to pass the reference of your Context to the Adapter from Your Activity (or) Fragment.

```
    public UsersAdapter(ArrayList<User> items , Context context) {
    usersList = items;
    this.context = context;
    }
```

Then upcast context to AppCompatActivity like this and get the getSupportFragmentManager

```
    ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Share to improve.

Comment: Kotlin: val fm = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager. In the Adapter Class: class MyAdapter(
    private val context: Context,

Answer (score 12):

Here you can set transition ;)

```
public void pushFragment(Fragment newFragment, Context context){

    FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Try this ..it worked for me.

Comment: whats view in view,getContext()? its unresolved reference in my code

Answer (score 6):

I worked as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.txtTitle.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtMessage.setText(list.get(position).getMessage());

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = list.get(position).getTitle();

                if(title.equals("FRECUENTES")){
                    RequestFrequentFragment fragment = new RequestFrequentFragment(); // you fragment 
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First you have to pass context to adapter constructor.

Then you have to use that context reference to get **`getSupportFragmentManager`**.

```
mCustomPagerAdapter = new NewPagerAdapter(context.getSupportFragmentManager());
viewHolderSecond.vPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: @Nabin ever find a solution?

Comment: try this ..this works for me ......FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Answer (score 3):

Another solution...

Declare context

```
private Toast mssgeToast;

private Context ctxContext;

public MyViewListener(myView pView){

    this.mView = pView;
    this.ctxContext = pView.getContext();

}
```

Next...

```
 public void pushFragment(Context context){
    FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    PopupClickFragment pcf = new PopupClickFragment();

    pcf.show(fm, "");
   // FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

}
```

and declare into onClickListener.
Example:

```
  @Override
    public void onCellClicked (@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder p_jCellView,int p_nXPosition,
    int p_nYPosition){
        //TODO: AQUI SE DEBE LEVANTAR EL POPUP INSTANCIANDO .SHOW();

        pushFragment(ctxContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For whome using **kotlin** you can use this solution

```
val dialog = IntervAddFragment()
       val ft = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        dialog.show(ft, ContentValues.TAG)
```

And it will work perfectly inchAllah.

Answer (score 1):

For those having this error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to YourFragment

I implemented this solution

Update your adapter constructor to accept the Fragment as a parameter.

Something like :

```
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
, getList, YourFragment.this);
```

and update the constructor of the Adapter :

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int id, YourFragmentfragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

then you call methods using the fragment variable.

```
fragment.doSomething();
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24502482/6914806) is by [Shivam Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239966/shivam-verma).

Answer (score 1):

just pass Avtivity

```
   `public CustomListAdapter(AppCompatActivity context, List<RowItem> rowItemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItemList = rowItemList;
}`
```

and you can do everything that you can do in activities but in your adapter class

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this way, in adapter method

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestViewHolder, position: Int) { 
val appCompatActivity = holder.itemView.context as AppCompatActivity
timePickerDialog.show(appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager, "dialog")
}
```

This solution works for me, getting context from holder, no need to send context to adapter also sending context in constructor to adapter as far as I know is bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.btm_ly, new SettingFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, try to not answer with code only, even if the code may work. Could you add text/link to docs?. Thanks.