# Refresh particular item in the list view

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, partial-page-refresh

I'm trying to update the particular item in the list view without refreshing the whole listview (Clearly explained below). For this requirement i fallowed almost all ideas which are available in online but i didn't get solution

Explanation:

I had different items in list view (See the attached image). For this list view i'm storing the id's and other related data by using model class (POJO class). In this same project i'm using push notification. In this push notification i'm getting the id of item which in my list view. According to the id i have to show some image in the list view. For this requirement if i refresh the whole list view i can change the image but i don't want refresh the whole list view. **So, i want to change the image of perticular item in the list view according the id which i'm getting from the push notification**.

**image**

[image]

**Example code** (I'm using the fallowing example code for filling the list view)

*Activity*

```
public class EventMyEventHosting extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<EventMyEventHostingItems> itemsaArrayList;
    EventMyEventHostingAdapter2 itemsAdapter;
    TextView tvNoEvents;
    ListView listView;
    boolean connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adapt_refresh);

        itemsaArrayList = new ArrayList<EventMyEventHostingItems>();
        itemsAdapter = new EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(EventMyEventHosting.this, R.layout.lv_my_events_hosting_adapter, itemsaArrayList);
                // (EventMyEventHosting.this,itemsaArrayList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_events_my_event_hosting);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        tvNoEvents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_events_my_event_hosting_no_events);

        loadDetailsVolley();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(EventMyEventHosting.this, EventMyEventDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("eventID", itemsaArrayList.get(position).getEventID());
                    startActivity(intent);*/


            }

        });
    }



    public void loadDetailsVolley(){


        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(EventMyEventHosting.this, null, null);
        ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(EventMyEventHosting.this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
        spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#009689"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(spinner);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        String eventMyEventHostingURL = "MyApi";
        Log.e("eventMyEventHostingURL", eventMyEventHostingURL);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, eventMyEventHostingURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                dialog.dismiss();

                if(response != null && !response.startsWith("<HTML>")){

                    Log.e("eventHostingURLOnResponse", response);

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        if(jsonArray.length() > 0){

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject singleJsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String postID = singleJsonObj.getString("id");
                                String title = singleJsonObj.getString("name");
                                String dateAndTime = singleJsonObj.getString("event_time");
                                String address = singleJsonObj.getString("address");
                                String isActive = singleJsonObj.getString("is_active");
                                String bgImage = singleJsonObj.getJSONObject("event_cover").getString("url");

                                EventMyEventHostingItems items = new EventMyEventHostingItems();

                                items.setEventID(postID);
                                items.setIsActive(isActive);
                                items.setTitleMyEvent(title);
                                items.setTimeMyEvent(dateAndTime);
                                items.setLocationMyEvent(address);
                                items.setImageMyEvent(bgImage);

                                itemsaArrayList.add(items);
                                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        }else {
                            tvNoEvents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }else{


                    Toast.makeText(EventMyEventHosting.this, "Please check your Internet connection...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                if(error != null){

                    Log.e("error", error.toString());
                }else{


                }
            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(EventMyEventHosting.this);
        queue.add(request);
        queue.getCache().remove(eventMyEventHostingURL);

    }
}
```

*Adapter*

```
public class EventMyEventHostingAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<EventMyEventHostingItems> {
    private Context context;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private List<EventMyEventHostingItems> items;
    String eventIdForVol;
    private EventMyEventHostingAdapter2 adapter;

    /*
    To remove item from list (Deleting the particular item)

    items.remove(rowItem);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // This is to show the no records found message

    import static com.app.hire.MatchedCandidates.listView;
    import static com.app.hire.MatchedCandidates.tvNoRecords;

    if(items.size() == 0){
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvNoRecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    */



    /*
    (This is for calling the Activity or fragment method from adapter)
    ===================================================================

    http://stackoverflow.com/a/24502482

    From your activity/Fragment initialize adapter like
    ---------------------------------------------------

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList, HomeFragment.this);  //HomeFragment.this for fragment

    In your adapter
    --------------

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int id, HomeFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    method calling
    --------------

    fragment.doSomething();
    */

    public EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(Context context, int resource, EventMyEventHostingItems[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, EventMyEventHostingItems[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(Context context, int resource, List<EventMyEventHostingItems> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = objects;
        this.adapter = this; 
    }

    public EventMyEventHostingAdapter2(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<EventMyEventHostingItems> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = objects;
        this.adapter = this; 
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        final EventMyEventHostingItems rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_my_events_hosting_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.eventImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_my_events_hosting_bg);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_events_hosting_adpt_title);
            holder.tvTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_events_hosting_adpt_time);
            holder.tvLocation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_events_hosting_adpt_city);
            holder.rlEnable = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_events_hosting_adpt_enable);
            holder.rlDisable = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_events_hosting_adpt_disable);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(rowItem.getIsActive().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            holder.rlDisable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rlEnable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            holder.rlDisable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rlEnable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if(rowItem.getTitleMyEvent().equals(null) || rowItem.getTitleMyEvent().equals("")){
            holder.tvTitle.setText("-");
        }else {
            holder.tvTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitleMyEvent());
        }

        if(rowItem.getTimeMyEvent().equals(null) || rowItem.getTimeMyEvent().equals("")){
            holder.tvTime.setText("-");
        }else {
            holder.tvTime.setText(rowItem.getTimeMyEvent());
        }

        if(rowItem.getLocationMyEvent().equals(null) || rowItem.getLocationMyEvent().equals("")){
            holder.tvLocation.setText("-");
        }else {
            holder.tvLocation.setText(rowItem.getLocationMyEvent());
        }


        if(rowItem.getImageMyEvent().equals(null) || rowItem.getImageMyEvent().equals("")){

        }else {

            Glide.with(context).load(rowItem.getImageMyEvent()).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_img).error(R.drawable.bg_480_800).into(holder.eventImage);

        }

        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.rlDisable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                eventIdForVol = rowItem.getEventID();

                Log.e("eventIdForVol", eventIdForVol);

                disableVolley(finalHolder);

            }
        });

        holder.rlEnable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                eventIdForVol = rowItem.getEventID();

                Log.e("eventIdForVol", eventIdForVol);

                enableVolley(finalHolder);

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView eventImage;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvTime;
        TextView tvLocation;
        RelativeLayout rlEnable;
        RelativeLayout rlDisable;
    }
}
```

*Pojo class*

```
public class EventMyEventHostingItems {

    private String eventID;
    private String imageMyEvent;
    private String isActive;
    private String titleMyEvent;
    private String timeMyEvent;
    private String locationMyEvent;
    private String interestedMyEvent;





    public String getEventID() {
        return eventID;
    }
    public void setEventID(String eventID) {
        this.eventID = eventID;
    }
    public String getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }
    public void setIsActive(String isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
    public String getImageMyEvent() {
        return imageMyEvent;
    }
    public void setImageMyEvent(String imageMyEvent) {
        this.imageMyEvent = imageMyEvent;
    }
    public String getTitleMyEvent() {
        return titleMyEvent;
    }
    public void setTitleMyEvent(String titleMyEvent) {
        this.titleMyEvent = titleMyEvent;
    }
    public String getTimeMyEvent() {
        return timeMyEvent;
    }
    public void setTimeMyEvent(String timeMyEvent) {
        this.timeMyEvent = timeMyEvent;
    }
    public String getLocationMyEvent() {
        return locationMyEvent;
    }
    public void setLocationMyEvent(String locationMyEvent) {
        this.locationMyEvent = locationMyEvent;
    }
    public String getInterestedMyEvent() {
        return interestedMyEvent;
    }
    public void setInterestedMyEvent(String interestedMyEvent) {
        this.interestedMyEvent = interestedMyEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. There's no need for this amount of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried hard to achieve this one but as i mentioned it's not possible to achieve (As of now). So, i achieved as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688490/3142611)

*Explanation*

When i'm getting the push notification, i'm simply calling the API which contains my ListView values and maintaining the ListView position like below code. During this API calling i'm not showing any progress dialog

```
Parcelable state;

@Override
public void onPause() {    
    // Save ListView state @ onPause
    Log.d(TAG, "saving listview state @ onPause");
    state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
}
...

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Set new items
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
    // Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
    if(state != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "trying to restore listview state..");
        listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
private void updateView(int index){
    View v = yourListView.getChildAt(index - 
        yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
       return;

    // Views you want to change
    TextView someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
    someText.setText("UPDATE");
}
```