# I have error in this class how to fix?

Tags: android, fragment, android-adapter

I'm using fragment in my project and I want to use `sqlite` database in part of project but I have error in part of The following class

```
package com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.fragments.CustomersFragment;

import java.util.List;

public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<Employee> employees){
        this.context = context;
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return employees.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return employees.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return employees.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_name);
        TextView txtPhone = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_phone);
        TextView txtAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_address);
        Button btnEdit = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        Button btnDelete = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        txtName.setText(employees.get(position).getName());
        txtPhone.setText(employees.get(position).getPhone());
        txtAddress.setText(employees.get(position).getAddress());

        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                **((CustomersFragment) context).editEmployee(employees.get(position))**;
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatabaseHelper(context).deleteEmployee(employees.get(position));
                employees.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

and my error message on android studio IDE is :

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.fragments.CustomersFragment

Note:

> Customersfragment is my fragment name and i have error in line 59
>   Inside two stars symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter already has a context. just use that.

```
  public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    private CustomersFragment fragment;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<Employee> employees, CustomersFragment fragment){
        this.context = context;
        this.employees = employees;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return employees.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return employees.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return employees.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_name);
        TextView txtPhone = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_phone);
        TextView txtAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_employee_address);
        Button btnEdit = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        Button btnDelete = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        txtName.setText(employees.get(position).getName());
        txtPhone.setText(employees.get(position).getPhone());
        txtAddress.setText(employees.get(position).getAddress());

        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragment.editEmployee(employees.get(position));
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatabaseHelper(context).deleteEmployee(employees.get(position));
                employees.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

If you set this adapter from Fragment class then just use this

```
adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), employees,CustomersFragment.this);
```

That's it.

More information you can follow this link.
[Call a Fragment method from an Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502394/call-a-fragment-method-from-an-adapter)

Comment: editEmployee is null error : Cannot resolve method 'editEmployee(com.androiddeft.navigationdrawer.Employee)

Comment: In this way, your context problem will be solved. Do you want to access fragment class from adapter right? I will update my answer.

Comment: this class error is solved, but now i have error in Customersfragment fragment You can download my project from here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a3WV5459HjRvWJeh0JntwePvGgRKs_UJ

Comment: @اندرولندandroland I updated my answer. Please see the last portion.

Comment: ok I understood,After changing the class by you class error is solved but now i have error in fragment please download my project and see customersfragment error in android studio ide thanks, I marked your answer as the correct answer But my problem is not resolved

Comment: I reviewed your code and its successfully build and run on a device. Actually, I am not better to understand the Arabic language. Please see my updated code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10FuYfpsguV32kgkbm_Av3hqxE4lwoZXR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you Mr ahmed my problem solved with your help, and me too because my main language is Persian and Azari

Comment: Welcome :-) Happy to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Use `getActivity()` inside the Fragment to obtain a Context that you can pass to `MyListAdapter` class using a constructor. That works, since Activity inherits from Context.

As alternative you can use `getApplicationContext()` to obtain the Context.

Comment: The context exists already, look at the error - its a `ClassCastException` - `(CustomersFragment) context`, just needs to remove the cast and use `context`.