# Communication between ParentFragment and Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, communication

I have a `MainActivity` which holds `HomeFragment`

`HomeFragment` has `sort` button `Viewpager` which holds 2 fragments

when `sort`  button is clicked in `HomeFragment`, the value has to be passed to `ViewPager Fragmensts`

I google where I found communication between Fragments which is placed directly in MainActivity

Comment: any hep ?......

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this by myself with the help of stackoverflow

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
    private var sort: Int = 0
    private var sortListener: SortListener? = null


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
            val childFragment = adapter?.instantiateItem(viewPager, fragmentPosition) as ChildFragment
            setSortListener(childFragment)
        }

    fun userClickinSort(){
sortListener?.onSorted(HomeConstants.SORT_TYPE_NAME)
}
    private fun setSortListener(sortListener: SortListener) {
            this.sortListener = sortListener
        }
```

Note: implemented this `SortListener` in ChildFragment