# Communicating between more than 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I have an activity with three fragments in it, This is how I communicate between the three fragments:

First I display only `FragmentA` in `ActivityA`. Based on a `RadioButtonSelection`, I add the corresponding `FragmentB` (two layouts available) and a `FragmentC`. If input in `FragmentB` is changed `String`, then `FragmentC's` views change but if the `RadioButton` choice in `FragmentA` changes then I remove `Fragment`B and `FragmentC` and add them again corresponding to input from `FragmentA`.

Now, I've implemented a communicator interface in `FragmentA` and another in `FragmentB`. It looks quite messy. How can I implement a single interface to communicate between the three of them and the activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such circumstances in which multiple fragments and activities want to communicate with each other, two options come in mind.

- [Java Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments) - Only **one** activity and one or more fragments. Each fragment should implement its own interface. Activity is also used for a shared channel among them. ***`Recommended`***

[image]
<sub>Image source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083101/1841194</sub>

- [Local broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) - Can be used among multiple activities and services. This also can be used for communicating between fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend implementing an interface. [Here](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/09/25/inter-fragment-communication/) is a good blog post guiding about Inter fragment communication.
If you do not want to implement interface then you can use Eventbus. A good library for that would be [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Comment: The instructions seem to be above my level of understanding. Are there some simple instructions?